# ListView with text and images

Tags: android, listview, layout

I'm trying to create a list view with text and images. Filling the layout works but I have a problem with `layout_height="wrap_content"` of the `ImageView`. After filling the List, the list items are twice as high as the image hight with a lot of space below and above the image itself. How do I avoid the empty space and wrap the `ListItem` height around the image?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_preview_product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_preview_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_preview_product" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `getView()` method from the modified adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_preview, parent, false);
    }

    Product product = getItem(position);

    TextView productText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_preview_product);
    productText.setText(product.name);

    // load image

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_preview_image);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(image);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: post a screenshot of 1. what you currently have and 2.what you want to achieve.

Comment: what is the size of your biggest image?

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on your ImageView and `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` did the trick! How do I accept a comment? XD

Comment: @A.S. post an answer...your solution seems to help OP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same Problem many times and setting

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

On my ImageViews did the trick, just give it a try. The Docs to adjustViewBounds says

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

if you image is big then set appropriate size here.

Answer (score 0):

set the weight of the layouts and their child widgets
android:weightSum="1.2"

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_preview_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:gravity="center" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/product_preview_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/product_preview_product" />
```

Comment: combination of match_parent and wrap_content :D

Comment: how can you specify a relative position in a linear layout ? And also, if it is relative, how can you give weights?

Comment: yeah need to use linearlayout and assign the weightsum.In relativelayout we can't give weights